# Does LLVM IR contains code for the built-in functions

Tags: c++, c, llvm, built-in

For built-in functions such as many math functions and `llvm.memset` and `llvm.memcpy` for example, Does LLVM IR contains the definition somewhere? Or they are just called and not defined in LLVM IR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those functions are defined in libc which is typically provided by your OS. Calls can be generated by LLVM (such as memcpy when doing a structure assignment).

Some math functions (abs) are defined. There is also a bunch of glue math (float-int conversion) which is called by llvm but defined in libcompiler_rt (which is a replacement for libgcc).

Other built-ins are defined in llvm such as __builtin_clz().